# Using female nouns to refer to males, how are adjectives affected?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, género, animales

Here is an English example where someone is referring to a man as a turtle:

> That turtle is slow. He is angry because he will not win. (calling that man a turtle)

In Spanish, the referenced subject is male (*hombre*), but the word used is female (*tortuga*). How are the adjectives *slow* and *angry* affected by this? Would they:

1. **Both be male**  because he is a man
2. **Both be female** because the word used is female (in this case, would the second pronoun be female?)
3. **Be of different genders**. *Slow* would be female because the subject of the first sentence is female, but *angry* would be male because the subject is a pronoun referencing the man directly.

---

**In other words, which of these is correct*:**

> Esa tortuga está **lento**. Él está **enfadado** porque no ganará.
>
> Esa tortuga está **lenta**. Él está **enfadada** porque no ganará.
>
> Esa tortuga está **lenta**. **Ella** está **enfadada** porque no ganará.
>
> Esa tortuga está **lenta**. Él está **enfadada** porque no ganará.

My bet is on the 3rd example.

*Unless my grammar is off.

Comment: I would say Ese "tortuga" está lento. Está enfadado porque no ganará. Because you are using "tortuga" as a substitute of the Name but the subject is still male whatever you call him. Except if you're trying to joke about his masculinity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAE explains this is the section "b" of this [entry](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=g%E9nero2):

> **Sustantivos epicenos**. Son los que, designando seres animados, tienen
> una forma única, a la que corresponde un solo género gramatical, para
> referirse, indistintamente, a individuos de uno u otro sexo. En este
> caso, el género gramatical es independiente del sexo del referente.
> Hay epicenos masculinos (personaje, vástago, tiburón, lince) y
> epicenos femeninos (persona, víctima, hormiga, perdiz). **La
> concordancia debe establecerse siempre en función del género
> gramatical del sustantivo epiceno, y no en función del sexo del
> referente**; así, debe decirse
>
> - La **víctima**, un **hombre** joven, fue **trasladada** al hospital más cercano
>
> y no
>
> - La víctima, un hombre joven, fue trasladado al hospital más cercano * (Incorrecto).
>
> En el caso de los **epicenos de animal**, se añade la especificación macho o
> hembra cuando se desea hacer explícito el sexo del referente:
>
> - La **orca macho** permanece cerca de la rompiente [...], **zarandeada** por las aguas
>   de color verdoso» (Bojorge Aventura [Arg. 1992]).

So the **adjective should agree the grammatical gender of the name** even if it has another adjective which indicates it's of a different sex.

So probably the best way of saying that is:

> Esa **tortuga macho** está **lenta**. (macho "indicates" it's masculine, but as tortuga is a femenine name it should be in femenine)

The second sentence can be both of these (depending on what the speaker wants to say):

> (**Ella**) está **enfadada** porque no ganará ("ella" substitutes "la tortuga")
>
> (**Él**) está **enfadado** porque no ganará ("él" substitutes "el animal" or "el macho" or any masculine name related)